# Метод класса, возращающий std::variant, содержащий этот класс

Tags: c++, c++17

Вообще без понятия как более адекватно сформулировать вопрос)
Как заставить `Function::call` вовращать `Value(std::variant<Nil, Number, String, Function>)`. Если что, этот код не скомпилируется.

```
#include <variant>

struct Nil {};
struct Number { };
struct String { };

struct Function {
    int idx_;

    template<typename ...Args>
    Value call(Args && ...args) {
        pushArgs(std::forward<Args>(args)...);

        callLuaFunction(idx_);

        return popValue();
    }
};

using Value = std::variant<Nil, Number, String, Function>;

Value popValue() {
    Value v = Nil{};
    //...
    return v;
}
```

**UPD:**
В дополнение к тому же вопросу, как быть, если добавить ещё 1 структуру `Table` :

```
#include <variant>

struct Nil {};
struct Number { };
struct String { };

struct Function; // <-- Предварительное объявление класса
struct Table; //UPD

using Value = std::variant<Nil, Number, String, Function, Table>;

Value popValue(); // <-- Объявление функции

struct Function {
    int idx_;

    template<typename ...Args>
    Value call(Args && ...args) {
        // ...
        return popValue();
    }
};

//------------UPD------------
struct Table {
    Value member() {
        return popValue();
    }    
};
//---------------------------

Value popValue() {
    Value v = Nil{};
    //...
    return v;
}
```

Думаю, новый вопрос создавать не следует, т.к. проблема практически та же.

Comment: Отредактировал ответ для случая с 2+ классами. В следующий раз лучше оставляйте комментарий под ответом, если что-то уточнить хотите, а то я правку только случайно заметил. В идеале, при этом лучше не редактировать вопрос.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот так:

```
#include <variant>

struct Nil {};
struct Number { };
struct String { };

struct Function; // <-- Предварительное объявление класса

using Value = std::variant<Nil, Number, String, Function>;

Value popValue(); // <-- Объявление функции

struct Function {
    int idx_;

    template<typename ...Args>
    Value call(Args && ...args) {
        // ...
        return popValue();
    }
};

Value popValue() {
    Value v = Nil{};
    //...
    return v;
}
```

---

**UPD:**

Если классов больше одного, то для всех, кроме последнего (хотя можно и для последнего тоже), методы, использующие тип `Value`, надо определять снаружи класса:

```
#include <variant>

struct Nil {};
struct Number { };
struct String { };

struct Function;
struct Table;

using Value = std::variant<Nil, Number, String, Function, Table>;

Value popValue();

struct Function {
    int idx_;

    template<typename ...Args>
    Value call(Args && ...args);
};

struct Table {
    Value member() {
        return popValue();
    }    
};

template<typename ...Args>
Value Function::call(Args && ...args) {
    // ...
    return popValue();
}

Value popValue() {
    Value v = Nil{};
    //...
    return v;
}
```